# How sin(90°+ θ) is equal to M'P'/OP' or Cos θ?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm learning Trigonometry right now with myself and at current I'm understanding how to find the trigonometric ratio of the angle (90°+ θ) in those of θ. I'm little bit confused right now in the Figure, I didn't get how angle **sin(90°+ θ)** is equal to **M'P'/OP'**.And how sin(90°+θ)=sin θ of triangle **P'OM'**[image: Image 1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qlar.jpg) 
[[image: Image 2]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIZ5X.jpg)Please help. Sorry If I'm asking foolish question. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Just another way we know $sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$ so here $a=\theta,b=90$ thus $$\sin(\theta+90)=\sin(\theta)\cos(90)+\cos(\theta)\sin(90)=\cos(\theta)$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't have reach upto this formula yet.

Comment: Formula isn't correct.

Comment: Whats wrong?? With it

Comment: Why are you answering this if you don't even know your trigonometric formulas?

Comment: Tell me the mistake

Comment: Oh sorrry !!! I dont know how i made such a silly mistake

Comment: can you explain me how sin(90°+θ)=sin θ of triangle P'OM'

Comment: It will be$ cos \theta$